# How to Show an image on a condition in Stimulsoft?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, stimulsoft

I want to show an image in Stimulsoft viewer on a condition,

like using a variable that gets its value from c#

like this :

```
If(variable == 1){Image.Visible = true;}
```

how is this possible in Stimulsoft ?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Visit :https://forum.stimulsoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=3056
i prefer to uncheck Enable Properties of Image then  write my expresion
a sample expretion will be:  var1==1